# Como fazer INNER JOIN entre tabelas no SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Gostaria de saber como fazer uma consulta mais elaborada usando INNER JOIN para juntar duas tabelas no SQLite para android. Eu sei fazer consultas usando INNER JOIN no MySQL. O quero saber é como fazê-las em uma aplicação android, se é da mesma forma e se não há nenhum problema.

Comment: Comando sql é uma linguagem própria e é adotada como um padrão entre os bancos relacional.

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost, sim mas, cada vendor cria seu próprio idioma e o AP quer saber como elaborar uma consulta complexa especificamente no SQLite

Comment: Joins no android são exatamente iguais ao Mysql.... Talvez o que vc esteja falando sejam funções, essas sim são distintas entre SGBDs. mas com consultas simples praticamente todos os bancos suportam com a mesma escrita. Se for o caso de alguma função detalhe mais o seu problema.

Comment: Depois de muito tentar, consegui fazer funcionar uma consulta utilizando INNER JOIN no Android SQLite. Vou deixar aqui pro caso de mais alguém precisar.

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT passeio._id, passeio.pas_duracao, passeio.gui_id, passeio.rot_id FROM passeio INNER JOIN inscricoes ON (passeio._id = inscricoes.pas_id) WHERE inscricoes.tur_id = ?", new String[] { Integer.toString(idTurista) });

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.columns, t2.columns //campos que você quer visualizar
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on (t1.column = t2.column) //você deve comparar com as chaves das tabelas
```

Esperto ter ajudado.

[Referência](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Se for usar o método query(), que só aceita uma única tabela como parâmetro de entrada, você pode criar uma view contendo esse join e passá-la para o método.

Se for usar o método rawQuery(), pode criar o JOIN normalmente na string SQL.